# Access to playbook variables from python module

Tags: ansible

When creating a custom module for ansible with python I need to access some of the variables in the playbook. I've found I can create a parameter to pass in the variables but is there a way to do access the variables without having to add a parameter each time?

For example, in a playbook I would have:

```
 - set_fact:
     myVariable: "some value"
```

In the script, I've tried:

```
import os
myPythonVariable = os.environ['myVariable']
```

But I get an error that the key 'myVariable' does not exist. I assume thats because I did not set it as an environmental variable. Is there a way to access non-environmental vars?

Comment: Try this : https://able.bio/rhett/how-to-set-and-get-environment-variables-in-python--274rgt5#:~:text=To%20set%20and%20get%20environment%20variables%20in%20Python%20you%20can,Get%20environment%20variables%20USER%20%3D%20os.

Comment: No, Ansible modules do not have access to playbook variables unless you pass them in explicitly.

Comment: @larsks, I suspect this is the case. Thanks